# MongoDB Sorting: Equivalent Aggregation Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following **students** collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f282eb2c5891296d8824130"), "name" : "Rajib", "mark" : "1000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f282eb2c5891296d8824131"), "name" : "Rahul", "mark" : "1200" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f282eb2c5891296d8824132"), "name" : "Manoj", "mark" : "1000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f282eb2c5891296d8824133"), "name" : "Saroj", "mark" : "1400" }
```

My requirement is to sort the collection basing on '***mark***' field in descending order. But it should not display '***mark***' field in final result. Result should come as:

```
{ "name" : "Saroj" }
{ "name" : "Rahul" }
{ "name" : "Rajib" }
{ "name" : "Manoj" }
```

Following query I tried and it works fine.

```
db.students.find({},{"_id":0,"name":1}).sort({"mark":-1})
```

My **MongoDB** version is **v4.2.8**. Now question is what is the equivalent **Aggregation Query** of the above query. I tried following two queries. But both didn't give me desired result.

```
db.students.aggregate([{"$project":{"name":1,"_id":0}},{"$sort":{"mark":-1}}])

db.students.aggregate([{"$project":{"name":1,"_id":0,"mark":1}},{"$sort":{"mark":-1}}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why it is working in `find()`?

As per [Cursor.Sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#interaction-with-projection), When a set of results are both sorted and projected, the MongoDB query engine will always apply the sorting first.

#### Why it isn't working in `aggregate()`?

As per [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), The MongoDB aggregation pipeline consists of stages. Each stage transforms the documents as they pass through the pipeline. Pipeline stages do not need to produce one output document for every input document; e.g., some stages may generate new documents or filter out documents.

**You need to correct:**

You should change pipeline order, because if you have not selected `mark` field in `$project` then it will no longer available in further pipelines and it will not affect `$sort` operation.

```
db.students.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "mark": -1 } },
    { "$project": { "name": 1, "_id": 0 } }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtgGl8AReeH

---

Comment: Can you explain how it works using find() query then, though it is not pipeline query?